# How to click on the div tag list element in selenium java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am not able to click on the list webelement. This is the HTML for the list. I need to click on the Admin tab.

```
<ul id="ctl00_PostIssueContent_PostIssueTrxLinks_TransactionTabsList" class="TransactionLinksTab listitem-cursor-pointer">
    <li>
        <div>Transactions</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>Restricted</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>Quotes</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>Admin</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried with the code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='TransactionLinksTabContainer']/ul/li[3]/div")).click();
```

but it didn't work.

Thanks for the reply. But none worked. the webelement in UI is a tab. In UI it has four tabs. If i click on that Admin tab, then a big list of elements will be dispalyed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3A82.png)

Comment: I updated the formatting in your question. In the future, please indent code and HTML with four spaces to have it properly formatted so that it's more easily read.

Comment: Please clarify what happens when your code runs... is there an error message or what happens? Please include the entire error message, if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to include the html. Is this a drop down list? Is is it a click to open the list or a mouseover?  Think of it in terms of, what am I doing as a user? If it is a mouseover you will want to hover over the element. If you have to click it first to open the menu, then do that first. Then to click on the element just do something like the below. I am more of a C# person but the below xpath may help.

```
//div[text()='Admin']
```

Comment: If you have questions, you should ask them in a comment. It makes your answer look less like an answer and more like an extended comment. The DIV contains the string "Admin", not the LI so you need to update your XPath. It also is an exact string match so you don't need `contains()`.

Comment: The html was not present when I wrote this. Correcting the xml.

Comment: err xpath. got cross contaminated working on something else heh

Comment: It is not a drop down. it is a tabs. it has four tabs..Transactions, restricted, quotes and Admin. I need to click on Admin. But i am not able to click on this list item.

Answer (score 0):

I think your XPath is just off. You seem to have started at some other parent element because the ID in the XPath doesn't match up with the HTML you have posted. Try this XPath instead:

```
"//*[@id='ctl00_PostIssueContent_PostIssueTrxLinks_TransactionTabsList']/li/div[text()='Admin']"
```

I corrected the ID, the descendants, and added the exact string match to "Admin" by using `text()`.

Comment: In what way did it not work? Error message or ? This XPath is correct given the HTML you supplied. If this doesn't work, you'll have to do more investigation and supply more info.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

*driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='ctl00_PostIssueContent_PostIssueTrxLinks_TransactionTabsList']//li/div[text()='Admin']")).click();*